# Flutter using BLoC Pattern for a state management in a big App

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-state

I have a qution about using BLoC in Flutter for state management how can I use it in a big app in the back I'm using Spring boot with enteties like (Student,Teacher,ClassRoom,Course ...) I do not know how many BLoC files I should define and with sych as I'm Using MVC Pattern I think that I should Create a BLoC for each Entety but I do not know if it is true!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes ... even thue you can use clean architecture design patten with bloc so the application will be maintainable and scalable .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).